# concise syntax for c++ namespace

Tags: c++, syntax, namespaces, std, using

I wonder if it is possible to write the following lengthy namespace usage in a more succinct way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using std::ostream;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ios;
using std::setw;
using std::setfill;
using std::hex;
```

say:

```
using std::{ostream,cout,endl,ios,setw,setfill,hex}; // hypothetically, of course
```

Comment: Short answer: No.  Is writting `std::` that big of a deal?  It causes so many fewer problems when you just use the qualified names.

Comment: ["Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1171191)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may write

```
using std::ostream, std::cout, std::endl, std::ios, std::setw, std::setfill, std::hex;
```

provided that your compiler supports the Standard C++ 17.

As for me then I advice to use qualified names instead of unqualified names introduced by using declarations. Unqualified names can confuse readers of the code and be reasons of ambiguities.

For example if a reader of the code will meet the name `hex` he will be confused whether it is the standard manipulator `std::hex` or a user-defined name.

Usually using declarations are used to introduce overloaded functions in a given scope or make visible names of members of base classes.

Comment: I hope nobody is confused by unqualified names from `std`.

Comment: @user253751 You are wromng. For example if you meet the name hex it is unclear whether it is std::hex or a user-defined name.

Comment: This appears to be valid for C++17, but not earlier versions - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration

Comment: Indeed this appears to be new in C++17. TIL. Please add that qualification to the answer

Comment: Note that Microsoft still appears to not support this syntax even with `/std:c++latest`

Comment: @AndyG No, Visual C++ 19 supports this syntax.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow [Not 19.00.23506](https://rextester.com/XPY39794)

Comment: Good to know they've fixed it in 16.4